# Bootstrap 5 Aligning Items In Navbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, navbar, bootstrap-5

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">

  <%= link_to "My Ozone", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <%= form_tag zipcode_path, :method => 'POST' do %>
    <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <%= text_field_tag 'zipcode', nil, placeholder: "Search Zipcode", class: "form-control mr-sm-2" %>
      <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: 'btn btn-outline-secondary my-2 my-sm-0' %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I've finished a Ruby on Rails project that displays ozone information based on the zip code searched for. However, I can't seem to get the field and submit button next to each other. I've tried a variety of different things like changing the div class and wrapping things in a form tag, but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue. Looking for help with getting the items aligned on the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `d-flex` instead of `form-inline` class in Bootstrap 5.

> Dropped form-specific layout classes for our grid system in **Bootstrap 5**. Use our grid
> and utilities instead of `.form-group`, `.form-row`, or `.form-inline` - [more details here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/migration/#forms)

Your code should be as below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">

  <%= link_to "My Ozone", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <%= form_tag zipcode_path, :method => 'POST' do %>
    <div class="d-flex my-2 my-lg-0">
      <%= text_field_tag 'zipcode', nil, placeholder: "Search Zipcode", class: "form-control mr-sm-2" %>
      <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: 'btn btn-outline-secondary my-2 my-sm-0' %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I believe I had tried d-flex, but didn't apply it to the right div class.

Comment: Don't forget to accept answer. if it does true and help you. Thanks.